# Change background color of link upon clicking with css when it has elements inside of it

Tags: html, css

Hello I have the following code

```
<div class="nhsuk-grid-column-one-third" data-test="recent-update">
     <div class="nhsuk-card nhsuk-card--clickable">
          <a class="nhsuk-card__link" href="{{ fullUpdateLink(0) }}" data-test="full-update-link-0">
            <div class="nhsuk-card__content">
                            <span class="nhsuk-caption-m nhsuk-caption--bottom">{{ updates[0].date }}</span>
                            <h3 class="nhsuk-card__heading">{{ updates[0].title }}</h3>
                            <p class="nhsuk-card__description">{{ updates[0].landingPageContent | safe }}</p>
             </div>
        </a>
  </div>
```

I would like to change that  links background to yellow upon clicking it with css. I have tried the following css and it doesnt work:

```
.nhsuk-card__link a:active {
   background-color: #ffeb3b !important;
}
```

I think its because of the elements inside of the  tag, I have tried without the div/span/h3/p elements and just putting in the word 'hello' and it works with that.

Comment: There is no `font` property in CSS.

Comment: If you want to change the background color `font` is the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: also you would need `:visited` selector. Better use would be JS and to add a class upon clicking.

Comment: Quite concerning seeing nhsuk classes in this one given the amount of false websites going around recently. Particularly as the live site uses those and would think anyone working on that site would have enough knowledge to know how to change a background color

Comment: my bad i meant back-ground color instead of font @tacoshy I tried using a:visited however no luck. I can't use js unfortunately im restricted

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Active will only so long as the action is currently 'active.' It works great for, say, clicking and holding a button to give it a more tactile look, but the changes will revert as soon as you let go of the click. :active won't listen for a click and keep the changes when the active state ends. Unfortunately, it just doesn't work that way.

Your best bet is to use an event listener with JS to add/change the div class on clicks. If you haven't used JS before, this can be a great practice, as you can do it with just a few lines of code. This tutorial can walk you through it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jznWWxPZkvQ